# How much size is used on dynamically creating a 2d array

Tags: c++

I want to know how much size is allocated in 2d array while creating it dynamically

suppose if i create a 1d array dynamically in c++ it will be like

```
int* p = new int[10];
```

which means 40 byte in heap memory and 8 byte in stack memory (according to my compiler)
but I am confused that how many memory will be allocated if I make 2d array
like(for 10*10 2d array)

```
int** p = new int*[10];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    p[i] = new int[10];
}
```

how much memory will be allocated in my stack and heap 
is it will be 80 byte in stack and 400 byte in heap 
or something else

Comment: Note that dynamically allocated arrays may have unspecified memory overhead not reflected by the `sizeof` the array object.

Comment: And don't write a 2D array like that. Use a 1D array with 2D access.

Comment: if pointer 8 bytes and int 4 bytes, then it will be 8 bytes on stack, 8*10 + 4*10*10 bytes in heap

Comment: @IłyaBursov a little bit more than that.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher right, but I suppose that implementation details are not important in this question

Comment: @ParikshitSingh -- Consider, if that array's rows are all the same length -- `int** p = new int*[10];` and then `int* pool = new int[10*10];` with all the `p` pointers pointing to locations in `pool`.  No need for allocations being done in a loop.

Comment: thanks @MatthieuBrucher for comment but I can you tell me how and why there will be little bit more storage I am a newbie and curious too, reply is appreciated

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher *And don't write a 2D array like that. Use a 1D array with 2D access.*  This depends on your use case.  Don't prematurely optimize.

Comment: Assuming you are working on a 32 bit system, int being 4 bytes then 10 x 4 bytes = 40 bytes for the array, for an array of pointers add an additional 40 bytes as each pointer requires 4 bytes, so the total for an arry of pointers will be 80 bytes.

Comment: @0x5453 it's not a premature optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one automatic variable of pointer type (not counting the loop variable). Thus, you use 8 bytes of stack (on your system).

You dynamically allocate one array of 10 pointers, thus 80 bytes on the heap. Then you allocate 10 arrays of 10 ints, thus 400 bytes more on the heap totalling 480 bytes on the heap.

Note that each separate dynamic allocation must be aligned to `alignof(std::max_align_t)`, and thus may potentially require padding of at most `alignof(std::max_align_t) - 1` bytes for each allocation. The allocator itself will use some memory for internal representation to allow efficient freeing of memory in arbitrary order. The automatic variable may need padding up to `alignof(int**) - 1`.